# Difference between JPA's AttributeConverter and Hibernate's ColumnTransformer in terms of Encryption and Decryption of attributes

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, encryption

I have a database which has some tables with encrypted columns. As of now, all these columns are of String type. I am using JPA's `@Converter` to encrypt and decrypt a column in a table. However, I also know, that I can use Hibernate's `@ColumnTransformer` to achieve the same objective of encryption and decryption while read and write operations. My question is how are they different and which is a better approach to use in terms of speed, maintainability, future enhancement, etc? Right now, `@Converter` is working fine with String type of data. I am not sure it will work with Integer type or I will have to create a new Converter class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They're very similar and in many cases can be used for exactly the same thing, but the implementations of the solutions varies a bit.

One primary difference is that one is Hibernate specific and the other is part of the JPA specification. If you want to write code matching the specification, use `@Converter` and you'll be able to use other implementations besides Hibernate with your code.

Another major difference is that `@ColumnTransformer` operates on the database level whereas `@Converter` reads the value from the database as is, then converts it to something else on the application side. This may provide performance advantages for `@ColumnTransformer` as the database performs some operations.

Additionally you can actually create an `AttributeConverter` that [applies automatically](https://www.thoughts-on-java.org/jpa-21-how-to-implement-type-converter/) to all values of a given type. This can be advantageous for example in refactoring situations where you don't want to manually add a `@Converter` annotation to many places.

So they can both be used to perform similar things and neither is implicitly *better* than the other.

Comment: Wow short and clear! Regarding the 2nd difference (3rd para), in a case where queries have 'like' clause, or some pattern matching, how will the @Converter work? Will it decrypt each row and column and then do the pattern matching or it simply won't work?
JPA query I would use would be something like this: "select p from Person p where p.name like :name". here column 'name' is AES encrypted.

Comment: You wouldn't want to query based on an encrypted column for at least performance and security reasons. I don't believe either mechanism can even handle a query like that using an encrypted column. If you do need that kind of functionality for some reason, you'd have to look into alternative solutions most likely comprising of full database encryption instead of single column encryption.

Comment: Thanks for all the info, that really helped.